# "/dev/mem" -- how to find GPIO mapping

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am interested to know how we can find out at which address are my hardware registers mapped on "/dev/mem".

Suppose if someone am interested to control GPIO using mmap command.

http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_Driving_Example_.28C.29

This link tell the mapping directly, but does not tell how can we find at what address does mapping for hardware devices starts ?

Please suggest on this point.

Any reply will be appreciable.

Regards.

Comment: Have you looked into this [question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/600/how-does-memory-mapped-i-o-addressing-work)?

Comment: [Here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2099/40) is another interesting question about it.

Answer (score 2):

The code you reference is using the following to address the GPIO controller.

```
// Access from ARM Running Linux

#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE        0x20000000
#define GPIO_BASE                (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000) /* GPIO controller */
```

The GPIO base address is 0x20200000

The code maps this address to an allocated piece of RAM (i.e. a buffer).

Comment: but data sheet says ;--